# Collection Fantasy story book

Tags: story-identification

When I was little (late 80s early 90s) my mom got me this book. I don't remember what it actually was about. It was for sure above my level at 5 or 6. I'm not even sure if she ever read it to me. It was hard cover and the book was silvery grey. No pictures on the cover. There was no dust jacket.

I do clearly and vividly remember the pictures. They were of wizards male and female. Their dragons and their castles. I also think there was a wizard for each season. They were BEAUTIFUL! I used to spend hours looking at it.

Each chapter was a different wizard, Dragon and castle. There was one for each season I think. I am pretty sure it started in spring or winter. Something is making me think the spring wizard was called the vernal wizard or something similar

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Have you asked your mom?

Answer (score 2):

This may be the [Dragonlance chronicles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance_Chronicles) by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman.

Note: I’m assuming you haven’t read the series but are mostly remembering the covers.

- The timing is right.
- The hardcover [dustcover](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images2/1/0816/10/dragonlance-chronicles-hardcover-oop_1_4ad8284e905b1ed0b6a9ce179872a22e.jpg) is white, so I'm assuming the cover itself could be silvery grey.
- The pictures were done by [Larry Elmore](http://www.larryelmore.com/store/) and are certainly captivating. He did a lot of work for D&D in general and Dragonlance in particular.
- There were three novels with three seasons: autumn, winter and spring.

  - Each cover had a dragon and one or more of the characters.
  - autumn had a female cleric with a magic staff and a red dragon.
  - winter had a female elf with a dragonlance, which kinda looks like a staff and a blue dragon.
  - spring had a red mage and staff and a green dragon.

Here are the the covers:

[image]

On the other hand, there were no combination wizards, dragons and castles, though dragonlords **were** paired with dragons.

Comment: I have a few Elmore original sketches he did for me at GenCon in '83 - fantastic stuff